# uwsgi breaks headers

Tags: http-headers, nginx, python-3.x, uwsgi

I'm using Nginx + uwsgi + python3

Sending any header via start_response goes well, but when I want to send more than one header, it becomes mad.
For example, if I write:

```
start_response('200 OK', [('Last-Modified', 'Wed, 11 Jan 2012 00:00:00 GMT'), ('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=windows-1251')])
```

The headers sent are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: nginx/1.0.11
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 11 Jan 2012 04:17:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-12
```

uwsgi sends the same header twice and even more the second one is broken.

Comment: one of the possible reasons is that strings python3 are kept in unicode, but http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/RunOnPython3k says there is no problem handling them

Answer (score 0):

which uWSGI and nginx version ? In both 0.9.8.x and 1.0.x i cannot reproduce your error.

You can check the real headers sent by uWSGI putting it in http mode with --http/--http-socket

Comment: That was the bug of uwsgi-python3 for ubuntu. I've just downloaded stable version of normal uwsgi, compiled it for pyhton3 and now everythings works just fine.